Finding $\frac{b+c}{a} + \frac{a+c}{b} + \frac{a+b}{c}$, knowing $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}=\frac32$, for $a,b,c>0$
We know
$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}=\frac32$$for $a,b,c > 0$. We need to find
$$\frac{b+c}{a} + \frac{a+c}{b} + \frac{a+b}{c}$$

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Apply AM-HM Inequality on the left hand side of the equation to get that equality is possible iff $a = b = c$.

$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}=\frac32≥3\sqrt[3]{\frac{abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}}$$
This gives $$2≤\sqrt[3]\frac{(a+b)(c+a)(b+c)}{abc}\\\implies 6≤3\sqrt[3]\frac{(a+b)(c+a)(b+c)}{abc}≤\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{a+b}{c}+\frac{c+a}{b}$$
Which happens if $a=b=c$.
Edit
I looked over a fact that the minimum value possible for $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}$ is $\frac 32$ according to the $AM-GM$ inequality, which occurs only when $a=b=c$. So we can directly conclude that our desired answer is $2+2+2=6$
